# Partition problems installing Ubuntu "Your installation medium is on /dev/sdb"

Tags: system-installation, partitioning

> Your installation medium is on dev/sdb1. You will not be able to create, delete, or resize partitions on this disk, but you may be able to install to existing partitions there.

I have gotten the above message while trying to install Ubuntu. I am reinstalling Ubuntu because of a crash that rendered me unable to boot Ubuntu so I decided to restart the reinstallation process only days after installing for the first time. This message appeared after I tried to change dev/sdb1 fat32 to ext2 in order to install Ubuntu to that partition. After I got this message I tried to select dev/sdb1 and press change but nothing happens no matter how long I wait for a response. I can’t format to fat32 as no root file system is defined. It tells me to correct this from the partitioning menu.

To be honest, I am completely new to Ubuntu and have no idea how to proceed at this point. I can’t install Ubuntu and can’t click change on dev/sdb1 fat32. Maybe I should try to completely wipe my disk clean? If needed I am able to access the terminal by entering try Ubuntu. Any help at all would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: You will probably want to format to ext4 instead of ext2 on the disk you install to.

Comment: If sdb1 was FAT32 was it an UEFI install? You should install in same boot mode as previous install, unless you had BIOS install but have UEFI hardware & want to upgrade to UEFI boot.

Answer (score 0):

When you make an installation, the installer detects **two disks** (or more): **the live USB you are running from** and **the hard disk** of your computer.

More often than not* the names of the disks will be:

**USB:** `/dev/sdb`

**HARD DISK:** `/dev/sda`

And the partitions of each disk is a number added to the name `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sdb1`, etc.

When performing the installation, you have to ensure that you select your HARD DISK (`/dev/sda`), not your USB (`/dev/sdb`), and **ensure that the boot loader (GRUB) is installed on your sda**.

* In some situations, the installer may detect the USB as `/dev/sda`, and the hard disk as something else.